# ¿Cuándo se usa "es" o "son"?

Tags: gramática, cópulas

Estoy hablando con un amigo que está en Canadá y dice que se le olvidó el español, pero parece que yo tampoco estoy seguro de cuál es la forma correcta o por qué.

¿Hay alguna regla para cuándo se usa el plural o el singular?

Aquí pareciera claro que se debería usar el plural:

> Lo que necesito **son** unos millones.

Pero si inviertes, esto parece ser correcto

> Unos millones **es** lo que necesito.

Y entonces ahora pienso que esto no suena *tan* mal.

> Lo que necesito **es** unos millones.

Comment: Creo que tenemos ya una pregunta sobre el tema de concordancia con verbos copulativos. Pero en resumen, vale tanto *es* como *son*, si bien la concordancia en plural es más común.

Comment: @guifa Tienes idea de que deberia buscar?

Comment: Estoy con @guifa: recuerdo haber leído una buena respuesta al respecto pero no la encuentro. Navegando por la etiqueta [cópulas](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%C3%B3pulas) debería aparecer, pero me temo que no hemos etiquetado demasiado consistentemente y será complicado encontrarla :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¿podría ser [esta respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13072/12637)?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo parece que sí

Answer (score 0):

`Lo que` es el sujeto, no "unos milliones".  Y por eso se usa "es" en vez de "son".

Comment: Podrías explicarlo un poco más aportando algunas fuentes? Es difícil hacerse a la idea de un sujeto como "lo que", pero aun así (yo por lo menos) no entiendo porqué entonces está clara que la concordancia es en singular y no en plural.